# Visual Basic global variables in Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I writing macro for excel on VB. 
There is a structure:

```
Forms
    Form1
Modules
    Main
```

In the Form1 I have Button click event

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
MsgBox GLOBALVAR 'I need access to GLOBALVAR here
End Sub
```

In the Main I have procedure Test

```
Sub Test
GLOBALVAR = "VALUE"
End Sub
```

How I can implement it? I can't create

```
Module GlobalVariables

End Module
```

Due to Excel does not support this construction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a

`Public MyGlobalVariable as String`

in the `Module1`

[image]

and it becomes accessible in your userform

[image]