# How to make a globally available collection

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function `readLines` that reads in 10 lines in an Excel sheet and returns a Dictionary. I want to store the results from this function in a global Dictionary that gets populated at start and then is global available to all other parts of my script.

What I would do in the case of an Integer is to declare the following in an empty module:

```
Public Cons GLOBAL As Integer = 1
```

however

```
Public Cons GLOBAL as Dictionary = readLines
```

Does not work for this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think your problem lies with `Cons`. Constant is constant :) So when you declare `Cons = 1 ` it is ok. When you are trying to declare `Cons = readLines` it does not work because you are setting it as a variable. Constant needs to be fixed values like `500`, you cannot change them. Instead of constant try declare your dictionary as variable (so just delete `Cons`) ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Basic global variables in Excel Macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141505/visual-basic-global-variables-in-excel-macro)

Comment: Plus, it's `Const`, not `Cons`. Plus, global variables/objects are a bad idea 99% of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can declare your global variable like that:

```
Public var As Dictionary
```

(no need for `Global`, check out about [Public,Private,Dim,Global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815547/what-is-the-difference-between-dim-global-public-and-private-as-modular-field))

Then inside a Sub or something you can initialize it:

```
Sub test()
    var = readLines
End Sub
```

You can't call a function to initialize a (global) variable outside a procedure